# Is there a way to "block" a t-test in R?

Tags: r, statistics

I'm looking for a way to "block" a t-test that will allow me to use three measurements per subject, instead of just averaging them.

**The problem is this**: My way of measuring has (intrinsically) big errors, so I measured the same subject three times to account for that error (technical triplicates). I typically block my ANOVAs or consider subject and technical repetition as a Random Effects in a Linear Mixed Effect model, in order to take the nature of my measurements in consideration.

However, in this case I only have treatment (5 subjects, 3 measurements per subject = 15) and control (7*3 = 21) in my set, so a t-test would be more adequate, but I cannot find a way to "block" a t-test. A paired t-test is not applicable since the treatment is not applied to the same subjects (would be impossible) and a normal t-test does not take in consideration the error within repetitions. Is there a function in R to do this?

Comment: What about doing a t-test on the averages within the subjects?

Comment: The problem with that is that it masks variation, e.g. s1 = (200, 200, 200) and s2 = (0, 600, 0) will appear the same, even though the latter is probably an artifact and the error will be artificially low (actually zero, for the case), risking a false positive. My measurements have a really big variation, so I'll go with Greg's answer. Thanks!

Comment: But if you're interested in testing for a difference between the treatment and the control it amounts to the same thing.  If you have a balanced design (same number of measurements on each subject) then averaging the responses within the subjects and doing a t-test will give you the same results as fitting a random effect for subjects and doing a test for treatment.  Sure you don't get an estimate of the within subject variation if you average within the subjects but you don't need that for the test anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A t-test is just a special case of ANOVA.  Take data that you would regularly do a t-test for and instead do ANOVA (2 groups, oneway) and you will notice that the p-value is exactly the same (if the t-test was 2 tailed) and the F statistic from the ANOVA is the square of the t statistic from the t-test (exactly equal if doing a pooled t-test, approximately if using the approximate t test).

So "blocking" a t-test is really just doing an ANOVA with blocking as well.

If you don't want to assume equal variances (the pooled t-test) then you can still do a mixed effects model instead of the ANOVA and just allow for unequal variances in the mixed effects model.

Comment: Thank you! you are absolutely right. I will do that. (Sorry for not upvoting your answer, I do not have enough reputation to do so)

Comment: I'm not really sure we want to do 'blocking' though.  The subject effect is actually what is interesting in this problem as the between subject variation is what we would want to use to test the treatment effect.  If we do fixed effects 'blocking' based on subject then we lose all of that info.  Honestly I think we *need* to make subject a random effect.  Since the design has the same number of reps within subject you can get the same analysis for the treatment effect by removing the replication by averaging within subject.

Comment: I think you're right. Since an ANOVA is an LME without random effects, I think it would be equally valid. 
I was planning on running a LME model y ~ treatment + 1|repetition + 1|subject, and compare it to a null hypothesis of y ~ 1 + 1|repetition + 1|subject; as I think is the most valid thing to do. 
I'm not sure as to averaging within subject though, I've never been a fan of averaging, specially in linear models. I have no argument for that but _intuition_ (I cannot quite do the proper math in mixed effect models, I'm a biologist)